# Disable OK button when text in text box is no longer correct format in C# Form

Tags: c#, wpf, button

This seems like it should be easy to solve, but my head is fried and I can't think of a good way to do this! Basically, I have a form with details on it. A user can click a button to pick a new PIN number. On this form, I have some Regex to ensure that the value entered in the textbox is a number and is greater than 4 digits.

Code for this:

```
this.buttonOK.Enabled = false;
        this.textBoxPin.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String pattern = @"[0-9]{4,}";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            if (regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text))
            {
                buttonOK.Enabled = true;

            }

        };
```

Now, OK becomes enabled if the PIN is more then 4 digits, but if you use backspace and end up with no digits, it doesn't matter - OK is still enabled from before. Is there any way that I can re-disable the button?

At the moment, I have an event from when OK is clicked and it's less than 4 - it pops up a warning message, as code illustrates below:

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxPin.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("PIN must be at least 4 digits!", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.Retry)
            {


            }
        }
    }
```

but with this way, I'm not sure how to revert the changes, as there are a lot of different things interacting in the bigger project that I'd need (basically, if it was cancel, I want to not save the changes etc.). This is why I think it would be easier if I could just re-disable the button if it was no longer correct. Is there any way of doing this?

Also, if I do press backspace, I'm then able to enter letters too, which shouldn't be allowed. I tried messing with Keypresses but I thought regex would be neater.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why can't you just do `buttonOK.Enabled = regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text)`?

Comment: I knew it was simple! Overcomplicating things is a common problem of mine! Okham's Razor etc - I hadn't even considered that solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text))
{
    buttonOK.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    buttonOK.Enabled = false;
}
```

Would that not work?

Shortened:

```
buttonOk.Enabled = regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
    this.textBoxPin.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String pattern = @"[0-9]{4,}";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        if (regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text))
        {
            buttonOK.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            buttonOK.Enabled = false;
        }

    };
```

?